# Fluent nHibernate Mapping issue

Tags: nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a DB with the following tables

- Users
- Roles
- UserInRoles (Bridge table for Users and Roles for many to many relationship
- Modules
- ModulePermission (this include the PK of Roles and modules and a bool field to identify the role has permission to access the module or not

now i m confuse about the Mapping of these table in fluent nHibernate, i did the mapping as define in [Fluent nHibernate Wiki site](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Getting_started) but getting this error:

> (XmlDocument)(3,6): XML validation
>   error: The element 'composite-id' in
>   namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'
>   has incomplete content. List of
>   possible elements expected: 'meta,
>   key-property, key-many-to-one' in
>   namespace
>   'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'.

Mapping:
UserMap:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Table("tblUsers");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(user => user.UserID).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
        Map(user => user.UserName).Not.Nullable();
        Map(user => user.Password).Not.Nullable();
        Map(user => user.IsActive).Nullable();
        HasManyToMany(user => user.RolesOfUser).Cascade.All().Inverse().Table("UserInRoles");
    }
}
```

RoleMap:

```
public class RoleMap : ClassMap<Role>
{
    public RoleMap()
    {
        Table("tblRoles");
        Id(role => role.RoleID).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(role => role.RoleName).Not.Nullable();
        Map(role => role.IsActive).Not.Nullable();
        Map(role => role.Description).Not.Nullable();
        HasManyToMany(role => role.Users).Cascade.All().Table("UserInRoles");
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what is the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Mapping for Role n User added.

Comment: I suggest you to write hbm.xml files to a folder to discover mapping issues!

Look here:

[Using Fluent NHibernate To Export / Create .hbm Files (NHibernate Mapping Files)](http://www.dotnetguy.co.uk/post/2009/10/19/using-fluent-nhibernate-to-export-create-hbm-files-nhibernate-mapping-files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HasManyToMany mapping configuration worked for me when I defined Parent and Child Key Column. You can do it like this:

```
HasManyToMany(user => user.RolesOfUser)
    .Table("UserInRoles")
    .ParentKeyColumn("UserID")
    .ChildKeyColumn("RoleID");
```